# I want to extract data using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a `string = "ProductId%3D967164%26Colour%3Dbright-royal"` and i want to extract data using regex so output will be `967164bright-royal`.

I have tried with this `(?:ProductId%3D|Colour%3D)(.*)` in python with regex, but getting output as `967164%26Colour%3Dbright-royal`.

Can anyone please help me to find out regex for it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex here, use `urllib.parse` module:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, unquote

qs = "ProductId%3D967164%26Colour%3Dbright-royal"

d = parse_qs(unquote(qs))
print(d)

# Output:
{'ProductId': ['967164'], 'Colour': ['bright-royal']}
```

Final output:

```
>>> ''.join(i[0] for i in d.values())
'967164bright-royal'
```

**Update**

```
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'%3D(\S*?)(?=%26|$)', qs))
'967164bright-royal'
```

Comment: Yes, but i need to use re module only to extract it.

Comment: Ah, jinx. Great minds think alike. I'll delete my duplicate answer since you beat me to it.

Comment: why do you **need** to? is this an assignment?

Comment: @VDN. I updated my answer. Is it an homework?

Comment: No this is not an assignment or a homework. It is a challenge i want to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative matches on the first part, you can not get a single match for 2 separate parts in the string.

If you want to capture both values using a regex in a capture group:

```
(?:ProductId|Colour)%3D(\S*?)(?=%26|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vEi1ID/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?:ProductId|Colour)%3D(\S*?)(?=%26|$)"
s = "ProductId%3D967164%26Colour%3Dbright-royal"
print(''.join(re.findall(pattern, s)))
```

Output

```
967164bright-royal
```

Comment: It is possible to catch both of them in one string?

Comment: @VDN You can not do that, as there is a "gap" between the 2 parts that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a regular expression and you can guarantee that the string will always be formatted the way you expect, you could try this.

```
import re

pattern = r"ProductId%3D(\d+)%26Colour%3D(.*)"
string = "ProductId%3D967164%26Colour%3Dbright-royal"
matches = re.match(pattern, string)

print(f"{matches[1]}{matches[2]}")
```